# Are ASP.net Content Web Forms able to access variables declared in the Code Behind section of it's Master Page?

Tags: asp.net, master-pages

I have a Master Page which controls the styling of my site. In the Code Behind, there are a few class instances instantiated as well as variables. These classes validate user access and then create user objects

I have a few Web Content Forms which carries out instructions based on the user objects. So far it seems that on each Web Content Form I have to create new instances of the classes found on the Master Page. This is doubling my work for every Web Content Form.

Is there anyway I can inhereit Classes and objects instantiated in the Master Page Code Behind?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Expose the objects (and even controls) as **public** properties (*get only for controls*) on the `Master` page. Then, in each `aspx` page you want access to these objects, add the following declaration at the top:

```
<%@ MasterType VirtualPath="~/MyMasterPage.master" %>
```

As @Kristof points out, simply access your properties like `Master.PropertyName`

Also, you can determine if it makes sense to store the objects in the users `Session` (don't forget that they must be serializable if you use DB for session state). I do this often and control access to them via properties in a base `Page` class that all my pages inherit from. Actually, I have a base `master`, `page`, and `usercontrol` so I have access to the same properties (for me it's `CurrentUser`) everywhere.

Comment: Correct. After doing that, you access the properties like this: Master.Property

Answer (score 2):

I believe you can if you make the properties public.
Then in your child-page you can make the call something like this:

```
SiteMaster master = (SiteMaster)this.Master;
master.MyProperty = 0;
```

Where `SiteMaster` is the class for your master page. (`SiteMaster` is the default for the app templates)

Though my mind can deceive me, I haven't done it for a while...

Comment: You don't need to cast if you set the Mastertype directive like Brad's answer

Comment: I know now :P But we wrote our answers at the same time, and I didn't know of that method.